# Fix "Procedure execution of ... failed on invalid input arguments" error

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I've been trying to write a script-fu script for GIMP 2.6+ that uses one of the built-in script-fu methods, namely the `script-fu-add-bevel` method.  My problem is that whenever I call it, either in the console or in my script, I get:

```
Error: Procedure execution of gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha failed on invalid input
arguments: Procedure 'gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha' has been called with an
invalid ID for argument 'drawable'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that
doesn't exist any longer.
```

This is really strange because I can clearly see by calling `gimp-image-get-active-drawable` with my image ID as the parameter that the layer ID that I'm passing to the script-fu method exists. The script is erroring while calling `gimp-drawable-type-with-alpha`, but I can call this method with the same ID in the console with no error.  How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this forum post](http://gimpforums.com/thread-gimp-batch-process-script-run-time-error), I learned that when calling a script-fu method, you **shouldn't** pass in the `run-mode` argument.  This is done behind the scenes, and if you pass anything for that value, **it will be interpreted as the second argument**!  This means that every argument you send in will be one parameter off, and it's only a matter of time before the script crashes.

So calling `script-fu-add-bevel` from another script-fu would look something like this:

```
(script-fu-add-bevel img layer bevel-width FALSE FALSE)
```